# How do I add other apps to Samsung's multi-window/sliding app in Android 4.1.2?

Tags: samsung, multi-window

I just got the Android 4.1.2 update.

I know how to disable the multi-window/sliding app section. I know how to add and remove the preassigned apps there, but how can I add other apps (e.g. camera, calculator, standard music player and other apps I have downloaded and installed)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add just any app to the multi-window list (the one you get by clicking **Edit**). That list only contains apps that have been written using Samsung's vendor-specific library to support the multi-window feature. (I suspect that the feature also has special-case code to enable the Google apps in the list such as Hangouts, but that's just speculation on my part.)

You can only make an app appear in that list by contacting the developer of the app and asking them to support it. It may be an up-hill struggle to convince them to invest time and make their app larger to support a feature used by a minority of users on one manufacturer's devices.

Comment: yes, I found where to disable it...under settings....display....multi window. but at that location you can only enable and disable, you have to edit the window onthe main page :)

I can understand for sure how the diff vendors may not want to convince them to support it!  thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

By default, you can't add other apps to Samsung's multi-window feature.

However, you can use apps like [Samsung Multi Window Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bjbinc.multiwindowmanager) to work around this limitation. It also has a [Pro version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bjbinc.multiwindowmanagerpro) that has additional features.

> Using this Multi Window Manager, you can enable ANY app to take
>   advantage of this awesome new feature.

Comment: I like the multi window feature, too bad they don't allow the addition of other apps. 

will try the Samsung Multi Window Manager, thanks for the inftormation

Comment: @Donald You're welcome. Please don't forget to upvote and accept if you're good any of the answers here. :)

Comment: Your phone needs to be rooted to use that app BTW.

Answer (score 0):

## Wanam Xposed Method

On a stock Samsung ROM, there is no option to edit the Multi-Window apps, and you can only select from a few apps.

However, you can work around this with an Xposed module called **[Wanam Xposed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ma.wanam.xposed)** which lets you customize which apps are shown in that viewz as well as many other aspects of a stock Samsung ROM. To use this, you will first need root. There are many tutorials about how to root various devices on the [XDA Forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com). You will then to install the **[Xposed Installer](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)** and then activate the xposed framework and the module. You should then be able to customize many things on a stock Samsung ROM, including the Multi-Window apps.

***Note: Please read all warnings pertaining to root, and research about root access before you try modifying your device, as it can lead to unwanted changes in your system. Always use caution when dealing with root or any modification of your device.***